# How to generate 6-digit unique numbers in C# or SQL Server?

Tags: c#, sql-server, random, unique

I want to generate 6-digit unique random numbers for my Users table. This unique code is different from table primary key. It should not be sequential and must be in 6-digit format. I have to ignore numbers like 111111, 222222, ...

I can use the Random() class in C# to generate it but the uniqueness is the key.

Is there any solution to do it in C# (or in SQL Server)?

Comment: One way to generate unique 'random' numbers is to encrypt unique inputs: 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, ...  Unique inputs will generate unique outputs.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can try this

```
    private static string GenerateNewRandom()
    {
        Random generator = new Random();
        String r = generator.Next(0, 1000000).ToString("D6");
        if (r.Distinct().Count() == 1)
        {
            r = GenerateNewRandom();
        }
        return r;
    }
```

Comment: Good solution @Mdhun, thanks.

Comment: it should be `r =GeneratenewRandom();` isn't it?